# SATA link reset

Tags: linux, disk, sata

I am getting this error:

```
[ 2614.727471] ata1: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4000000 action 0xe frozen
[ 2614.727477] ata1: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[ 2614.727481] ata1: SError: { DevExch }
[ 2614.727488] ata1: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[ 2614.727491] ata1: hard resetting link
[ 2615.450561] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
[ 2615.450577] ata1: EH complete
```

and I DO NOT HAVE ANY SATA disk drives connected. I have an IDE disk!!!

my kernel version is recent: 4.2.8-300.fc23.x86_64 , Fedora 23, 
motherboard: ASRock supercomputer X58

Why is it telling me I have a link if that is not true? Is there a way to diagnose this? I suppose the IDE interface on my motherboard is somehow mapped to SATA controller, so the error I am getting is not originated from the disk, but from the controller. Then, why does it tell me that it is resetting the link to 1.5 Gbps??? Maximum IDE speed is 133MB/s. Very weird. And btw, I the disk is working perfectly without any problems.

Comment: So, what is plugged into the SATA port?

Comment: NOTHING!!! all SATA ports are free

Comment: the interesting thing, is that this message shows more frequently when I watch youtube videos , I suppose due to that the videos are downloaded to disk.

Answer (score 1):

It was a hardware fault. I bought a PCI express SATA adapter card, disabled the SATA adapter on the motherboard and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad you found a workaround. I'd suggest, mainly for anyone else finding this page, that *you shouldn't rule out a driver, kernel or BIOS bug*. The PCI card may be using a different SATA controller, and thus different BIOS and driver code.

Your particular board uses an Intel ICH10R. There were reports that the ASRock Supercomputer X58, either in its BIOS or in its chipset drivers, had a bug that fouled up the SATA controller's state when resuming from sleep, due to a PCIe interface mode not being properly set. Potentially this might have been causing your issues, although that is supposition on my part.

Do you know your BIOS is up to date? (There are 21 BIOS versions for this board. See https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/X58%20SuperComputer/index.asp#BIOS . )

---

To identify your BIOS version, try

```
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
```

or, perhaps more usefully

```
inxi -M
```

since you'll also get build date and a bunch of other useful information. If you don't have *inxi* installed, on an APT based distribution, first use `sudo apt install inxi`. (If you want a real trove of useful info on your machine, use `inxi -F`. To get serial numbers etc, issue this command as root.)

To identify a SATA controller when you don't have access to relevant documents, I'd recommend the following two commands:

```
lspci | grep SATA
```

and

```
dmesg | grep AHCI
```

These will give information on your SATA controller, and its connection topology, respectively, where the correspondence between the two is shown by the first item in each output, in case you have more than one controller.

Armed with this information, it's much easier to find reports of similar problems, as well as related bugs on kernel/driver bug trackers.

---

On several occasions I've had what looked like hardware problems, which were really caused by *newer* kernels running on *older* hardware. Sometimes testing an old live distro or installing an old version to an unused drive can be instructive; with 2010 hardware, if an OS build from say 2011 doesn't show the problem you can be fairly confident the hardware is okay. (My most recent instance of this was a bug in *zram*, which looked really convincingly like a hardware issue, since it would completely freeze the entire machine (including mouse, caps-lock etc.) while writing nothing to the logs. Turned out to be a regression introduced by a kernel update. I wasted a lot of time tracking that down.)